# Siegel's formula for generalized theta series with characteristics?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, modular-forms, quadratic-forms

Siegel's formula(Siegel-Weil) directly relates the weighted sum of theta functions to Eisenstein series. (Or equivalently, the weighted sum of the cusp form is zero). I wonder if there is a generalization to theta functions with characteristics?
Thanks!